# Complete explanation about Context API in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm a little bit confused about how Context API works

as the docs said about [Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider):

> Accepts a value prop to be passed to consuming components that are descendants of this Provider. One Provider can be connected to many consumers. Providers can be nested to override values deeper within the tree.

I just start to try a simple code like this:

```
//App.js

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeColor=(color, value)=>{
      this.setState({[color]:value})
    }
    this.state={
      changeColor:this.changeColor,
      red:0,
      green:0,
      blue:0,
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <InitialScreen/>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

//InitialScreen.js

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {({red, green, blue, changeColor})=>(
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
              <Text>Red: </Text>
              <Slider
                style={{width:'80%'}}
                minimumValue={0}
                maximumValue={255}
                step={1}
                value={red}
                onValueChange={(e)=>{changeColor('red', e)}}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
              <Text>Green: </Text>
              <Slider
                style={{width:'80%'}}
                minimumValue={0}
                maximumValue={255}
                step={1}
                value={green}
                onValueChange={(e)=>{changeColor('green', e)}}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
              <Text>Blue: </Text>
              <Slider
                style={{width:'80%'}}
                minimumValue={0}
                maximumValue={255}
                step={1}
                value={blue}
                onValueChange={(e)=>{changeColor('blue', e)}}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={[GlobalStyles.Center, {flex:1, backgroundColor:'rgb('+red+', '+green+', '+blue+')'}]}>
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

//themeContext.js

import React from 'react';

export const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: '#000000',
    background: '#eeeeee',
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: '#ffffff',
    background: '#222222',
  },
};

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: themes.dark,
  toggleTheme: () => {},
})
```

I don't know what's the meaning of `Object` inside `React.createContext({...})`, i can pass `this.state` in `Provider value props` that's mean I don't need to define anything in `React.createContext({...})` AFAIK,

or maybe I'm doing something wrong so I'm out of `Context` function itself?

Comment: React.createContext is documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) - which is just above the documentation yu partially quoted

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't really get it about **The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. This can be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them**, I've tried to `console.log(this.context)` but nothing is printed in the log, how can i access the `defaultValue` itself btw?

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right, you don't need to provide anything in React.createContext in order to use it. The data you provided in createContext is merely default value and will be override as you set Context.Provider later on. However, I **strongly** recommend you to always provide a default value because of the following reasons:

1. By doing so you can think ahead of what kind of data your context would serve, hence help you to understand the structure of your code better. This habit would help you in long run
2. It gives whatever IDE you're using (Visual Studio for example) a clue of your Context data and it would give better hints as you code

Comment: so, if I've defined the default value, how can i access the default value itself? when I've pass `this.state` in `value props` of `Provider`, does the default value is replaced?

Comment: @flix yes, the default value will be overridden